# Checking users current password when changing account settings

Tags: php, cakephp

I am building a form for a logged in user to change their account settings (email and password). To do this, they need to be able to confirm their current password. This is how I'm building my form in `settings.ctp`:

```
<div id="content-complex-image">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/account/images">Your images</a></li>
            <li><a href="/account/settings">Account settings</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content-inner">
        <p>Modify your account settings</p>
        <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->create('User');
            echo $this->Form->input('currentPassword', array('type' => 'password'));
            echo $this->Form->input('username', array('disabled' => 'disabled', 'value' => $username));
            echo $this->Form->input('email');
            echo $this->Form->input('password', array('type' => 'password'));
            echo $this->Form->end('Update');
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

and this is my controller action:

```
public function settings() {
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Account Settings');

    $this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if($this->Auth->user('password') == $this->request->data['User']['currentPassword']) {
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your details have been saved');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'settings'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your details could not be updated. Try again.');
            }
        } else {
             $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid password. Try again.');
        }            
    }
}
```

However, the `if()` for a password check always evaluates to false and always shows the "invalid password" message. I'm guessing I'm not checking the password correctly, but I don't know the correct way to do it.

Also, I don't want the user to be able to change their username. I know I've set the form field to disabled, but if a user sends a post request to my settings action they could change their username. How do I stop the username from being updated with `$this->User->save()`?

EDIT: Looks like two problems, one, I wasn't hashing the password before the comparison and two, `$this->Auth->user('password')` is actually NULL. Which raises another question, how do I get the users hashed password from the database in order to compare it?

Comment: Is the password stored in your database using plaintext? If not, that would cause your validation check to fail.

Comment: It's using Cake's default hashing algorithm, which I believe is sha1?

Comment: you'll need to hash the `currentPassword` as well so that it matches whatever `Auth::user('password')` is

Comment: also note that even though the `username` is disabled; a determined user could modify it - so I would `unset` it before you save to prevent the username from being overwritten accidentally/on purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the password isn't stored in your database as plaintext then the password check will fail since you are not encoding / encrypting the data you are passed from the form. An easy way to check that (only on a test machine please) would be to replace `$this->Session->setFlash('Invalid password. Try again.');` with

```
$this->Session->setFlash('The password should be ' . $this->Auth->user('password') . 'but it is actually ' . $this->request->data['User']['currentPassword']);
```

or something similar.

Hope it helps

edit:

If the password is stored using sha1, you can check it like this

```
if($this->Auth->user('password') == sha1($this->request->data['User']['currentPassword']))
{
     //code for successful password here
}
```

Comment: After doing that, I get this: `The password should be but it is actually password`. After doing a `var_dump` on `$this->Auth->user('password')` I see that it's NULL. Looks like Cake doesn't store the users password in the Auth component like it stores the username and user id. :(

Comment: you might want to validate the user based on something else, like a session ID? The Auth component is probably in a Session object which would be too easy for a malicious user to hijack.

Comment: I should add that I haven't used Cake before, just plain PHP.

Comment: If it doesn't show you password, use: $variable = $this->Auth->user(); debug($variable);.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct about the Auth component not holding the password in it's data. Try this code out:

```
public function settings() {
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Account Settings');

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->User->findById($this->Auth->user('id'));
        if($user['User']['password'] == AuthComponent::password($this->request->data['User']['currentPassword'])) {
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your details have been saved');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'settings'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your details could not be updated. Try again.');
            }
        } else {
             $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid password. Try again.');
        }            
    }
}
```

And my suggestion for stopping them from changing their username is to just discard that input altogether? You could simply echo their username for them rather than have a disabled input box.

Comment: Thanks, works. I could disable the input but the user will still be able to change their username by sending a POST request to that page with a `username` parameter, because of the way Cake handles user saving. I've opted to use `unset()` instead, to make sure even if the `username` field is sent it's discarded.

Comment: I didn't consider how the save() function handles saving, unset() is exactly what you should be using in that case. Also, if you'd like to optimize the query you could use containable to make sure it only returns the data you need.